# Contacts app behaviour

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts, 5.1-lollipop

I'm running Cyanogenmod 12.1 and I'm having problems with the Contacts app.

A particular contact is showing in the Gmail app and in the phone app but not in the Contacts app.

Then I noticed that if I go to the phone app and select "Add contact" it shows up in the contacts app.

I cannot understand the logic behind this behaviour. Isn't Android supposed to sync my contacts with my Google account? Then why do I have to browse for a contact in Phone to "add contact"?

Comment: Do you have a filter selected in Contacts?

Comment: Are you using a stable or a nightly build of CM12.1? Which particular build is it and for which device? If you're on a nightly, have you tried with a stable one and see if the issue persist?

Comment: It's an unofficial build for Samsung S3mini by novafusion.pl

Comment: @MatthewRead No filter is set. It seems that not all contacts are automatically synced with Google.

Comment: Just found a duplicate of my question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87256/not-all-google-contacts-show-up-in-contacts-app-but-in-phone-app?rq=1